# Are DPC latency issues improved with multiple cores?

Tags: multi-core, dpc

[DPC latency checker](http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml) says

> A device driver cannot process data
>   immediately in its interrupt routine.
>   It has to schedule a Deferred
>   Procedure Call (DPC) which basically
>   is a callback routine that will be
>   called by the operating system as soon
>   as possible. ... **There is one DPC
>   queue per CPU available in the system.**
>   ... If any DPC runs for an excessive
>   amount of time then other DPCs will be
>   delayed by that amount of time. ...
>   Unfortunately, many existing device
>   drivers do not conform to this advice.
>   Such drivers spend an excessive amount
>   of time in their DPC routines, causing
>   an exceptional large latency for any
>   other driver's DPCs. For a device
>   driver that handles data streams in
>   real-time it is crucial that a DPC
>   scheduled from its interrupt routine
>   is executed before the hardware issues
>   the next interrupt. If the DPC is
>   delayed and runs after the next
>   interrupt occurred, typically a
>   hardware buffer overrun occurs and the
>   flow of data is interrupted. A
>   drop-out occurs.

[Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920969/automatic-dpc-latency-testing-how/2921142#2921142) says:

> A DPC is queued into the global DPC queue, and can be run on any processor. So if you really have a long (-running) DPC on one core, the other core is free to process another. So any timing information is really dependent on the count of processors you have and how many things get currently executed concurrently. So on multicore processors these numbers might vary widely.

Generally what I've read is that a fast dual core is better than a slower quad core for audio, since most audio apps aren't optimized to use more than one core.

But in modern computers it sounds like DPC issues are bottleneck for audio production.  Does this mean a quad core processor would be better than a dual core?  Other free cores could theoretically handle the audio DPCs while one is locked up by a rude Wi-Fi DPC routine.  Is the queue shared between cores, and DPCs can be shuffled around to whichever one is free?  Or is there one queue per core, allowing for a core to be hijacked?  What about virtual cores?

Comment: If you had both systems you could use this tool to compare and get real world data...http://www.thesycon.de/eng/latency_check.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Latency in a Deferred Procedure Call (DPC) is caused by a driver taking a long time to do its thing.

Adding more CPUs will not improve the time a poorly written driver takes to do its processing.

Comment: Can you back up your opinion with facts?  There's a separate DPC queue for each CPU.

Comment: i cannot. Kernel mode code cannot be multi-threaded. And the only time there's an issue with DPC latency is when a poorly written driver is behaving poorly. Throwing more cores at it won't make it run gooder.

Comment: The question asked was not "will more CPUs make a bad DPC run faster?" The question is "will more CPUs let my audio driver run when a badly behaved driver is also installed in the system?"

Comment: Then his only option is to buy the faster machine [and observe for himself that things are not any better](http://superuser.com/a/247713/8169)

Answer (score -2):

Resurrecting an old thread (sorry). Seems to me the promise of parallel computing and multi cores has not been fully delivered for audio work. In the (good?) olden days (as noted above) when dual processors became possible, the promise was that one processor could handle the graphics while another focused on audio. And you solved DPC issues with tweaking and higher audio buffers. And that worked as an efficiency improvement in some DAWs (eg Logic). But now my newish laptop has eight cores (supposedly like 8 separate processors - or 16 with hyperthreading on) and DPC latency issues are just as bad as ever. Even with wifi and most other features switched off, full power and largish buffers (512 samples), there's still the occasional glitch on DJing software (which is not itself taxing the CPU much). DPC latencies of 4,000-10,000! I live in terror of it occurring in performance, hence have been careful to use this machine in non-critical situations only. My desktop dual Xeon audio workstation, on the other hand, has DPC consistently around 500 and is perfect. Maybe the trick really is dual actual CPUs not cores.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).